# Add, subtract and compare date and time on Meteor Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, meteor

I am running a collection on Meteor Mongo that has a field called `last_activity` and another one called `expire_date`.

In this particular case I need to get items from that collection whose `last_activity` was N hours ago.

In a second case I have to save an `expire_date` that is N months from creation time (right now).

How can I add or subtract date or time on Mongo/Meteor (if they use different methods I would be glad if someone explained both briefly) and make comparisons with them?

Plus, which one is the best idea to choose when we are getting something from the database? Will I save some processing time if I do it directly on Mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how do you store your date. You have at least two options.

```
Date.now()
1437215759517
```

or

```
new Date()
Date 2015-07-18T10:36:04.981Z
```

In first case it is amount of ms from some special point of time in linux(unix) world :D
And you can easily add any time to existing one. For example:

```
1 week
7 * 1 days
7 * 24 hours
7 * 24 * 60 minutes
7 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds
7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ms
```

So in your code you will have something like this (1 week from now):

```
expire_date = Date.now() + 7 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

And yes. To display this date in eye-pleasing format I would suggest [moment.js](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment)

```
Date.now()
1437216383841

moment(Date.now()).format('LL')
"July 18, 2015"

moment(Date.now() + 7 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).fromNow()
"in 7 days"
```

Comment: And how do you compare dates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Moment.js to add or subtract time in readable English. There's a [Meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) to install Moment easily.

```
$ meteor add momentjs:moment
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

---

```
moment().add(Number, String);
moment().add(Duration);
moment().add(Object);

// For example, add 7 days from now:
moment().add(7, 'days');
```

---

After you generate the right date object you can persist it on your Mongo database.

Answer (score 1):

Store all date|time in ISO - {createdAt: ISODate("2015-08-12T09:36:42Z").
Use momentjs:

```
moment().toDate()
var currentDateInISO = moment().toDate()
posts.insert({createdAt: currentDateInISO});
```

Compare 2 ISODate:

```
var t1 = moment().toDate()
var t2 = moment().toDate()
moment(t1).isBefore(t2) // True
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

Have fun.